# Getting error on installing lightning app

Tags: lightning-apps, package-install

I am undergoing a painful issue for installing a lightning component managed package.I am getting this error every time I try to install package in any dev org - 
`There were custom validation error(s) encountered while saving the affected record(s). The first validation error encountered was "{0}".`
The weird thing is that the same version package has installed successfully in one of my test org , but now it is giving error. 
I have not defined any validation rules in my package also.
After some digging I found that there are some components of the package in packaging org that are not present in the test org.That component is simply a protected custom settings and its fields.
The error message is also not that informative that I can take any clue out of it. 
Require assistance. Thanks in advance !